# SQL regex words with space

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

I've got a code:

```
$phrase = "hello";

SELECT (...) WHERE x RLIKE '[[:<:]]$phrase[[:>:]]'
```

but when I want to search for a phrase with space at the end:

```
$phrase = "hello ";
```

the search returns nothing

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Sorry, if you do not need to check word boundaries, why bother and use RLIKE? Use `LIKE '%$phrase%'`. Also, why did you use the `xregexp` tag (JavaScript one)?

Comment: cause I want to search for a phrase as a word

Comment: Yeah, but "hello " is not a word. It is a word with a space. Space is not part of a word.

Comment: Please define the "word boundaries" for this project.

Answer (score 0):

For MySql you should use `[[:space:]]` in order to find the white space

```
"SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_field REGEXP '$phrase[[:space:]]'"
```

But ya - if your $phrase already contains a space in it then just:

```
"SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_field like '%$phrase%'"
```

*Im not sure how the assigning of the value of `$phrase` into a string works in php but as far as the sql part it should work*

Comment: I think he wants to be able to feed in a phrase already containing a space, and have it work inside the query.  But I could be wrong.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I believe you are right - I'm not strong with php so I just left that part matching the example he gave (preferred that on offering to do string concatenation in order to construct the query :))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match a pattern whose final character represents the end of the phrase, then you can use the `$` regex delimeter:

```
SELECT ...
FROM yourTable
WHERE x REGEXP $phrase . '$'
```

Assuming the phrase were `"hello "`, the regex you would want to match would be `hello $`

Comment: nope. I just want to search for a phrase as a word, and that it'll be able to also search for a phrase containing space

Comment: @user6638766 Yup.  This is what my answer should be doing.

Comment: @Tim you know well your answer is not "doing" that. `$` matches the end of string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Things are confusing, because the query itself will appear inside PHP code.  I suspect that you are reading what I wrote literally, which off course won't make any sense directly to MySQL.  The point I was trying to make is that if he wants to match ending with a space, he should be using `$`.

Answer (score 0):

The `[[:>:]]` is a trailing word boundary. When you pass `"hello "`, the resulting pattern is `'[[:<:]]hello [[:>:]]'` which means it will match "hello " followed with a trailing word boundary - which will never happen as the space is not a word character.

It makes no sense using the word boundaries here, use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT (...) WHERE x LIKE '%$phrase%'
```

or

```
SELECT (...) WHERE x LIKE CONCAT('%', $phrase, '%')
```

If you still want to make sure your search *phrase* does NOT appear in-between word chars, use

```
SELECT (...) WHERE x RLIKE CONCAT('(^|[^[:alpha:]])', $phrase, '($|[^[:alpha:]])')
```

Another way out: just keep the `[[:<:]]` *leading* word boundary, and remove the *trailing* `[[:>:]]` one.

Answer (score 0):

Before using the $phrase, do

```
$phrase = trim($phrase);
```